# Insert into mongodb freezing without error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This is my database connection:

**app.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
var { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017", (err, client) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  db = client.db("MyDb");
  app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log("listening on 5000");
  });
});
```

And this is my `insert` function:

```
router.post(
  "/register",
  [
    check("email")
      .notEmpty()
      .withMessage("Email Field is empty"),
    check("email")
      .isEmail()
      .withMessage("Your email is not valid")
  ],
  function(req, res) {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (errors.length >= 0) {
      res.render("register", { errors: errors.errors });
      console.log(errors.errors);
      return;
    }

    const { name, email, password } = req.body;

    const newUser = new User({
      name: name,
      email: email,
      password: password
    });

    newUser.save(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;

      console.log(true);
    });
  }
);
```

And this is my user model:

**User.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, require: true },
  email: { type: String, require: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, require: true },
  created_at: Date,
  updated_at: Date
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

There is no error in terminal or browser. When I click the "register" button, the app will freeze and there is no error message at all.

I already tested many tips concerning the database connection but couldn't solve the issue.

Comment: So one key issue is that you aren’t sending any status/response/json/page inside the save handler for user so the consumer of this endpoint will never get a success or error response. What are you intending on happening when a new user is saved successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find there are two order of problems in the proposed code, at least as we can read it in your question:

1. First, I can't find any binding between *mongoose* and the established mongodb connection
2. Second, your route handler does not seem to return any status code / content to the 
   caller

So, for as I see it, you can

1. change connection setup as follows

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', {useNewUrlParser: true})
    .then((conn, err) => {
    app.listen(5000, () => {
        console.log("listening on 5000");
    });
});
```

in order to  bind *mongoose*  with MongoDb configuration

2. retust a status code, e.g. 201, when the new `User` has been saved:

```
newUser.save(function(err) {
    console.log('Result', err)
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log(true);
    res.send(201)
});
```

This way I prevent the application hanging up on receiving request...

I hope this can help you!

Answer (score 0):

`validationResult()` "Extracts the validation errors from a request and makes them available in a Result object." https://express-validator.github.io/docs/validation-result-api.html Therfore, if you don't have any errors this object will contain no errors ( you can check with `.isEmpty()`), your endpoint doesn't send a response, and leaves the requestor waiting.